# How to fail `yarn install` when there are warnings during post-resolution validation?

Tags: yarnpkg

I'd like `yarn install` to fail when there are warnings in the post-resolution validation, so that we can catch these problems in CI. You'd think this would be a simple command-line flag, but I'm not finding anything in the docs to do this.

I tried `yarn install --json` in the hopes of finding these errors, but they're not being printed. (The command isn't printing anything at all.)

This is the type of error I'd like to catch.

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Post-resolution validation
➤ YN0002: │ my-package@workspace:packages/my-package doesn't provide react (p33108), requested by my-dependency
➤ YN0002: │ my-package@workspace:packages/my-package doesn't provide react-dom (p567a9), requested by my-dependency
➤ YN0002: │ my-package@workspace:packages/my-package doesn't provide urql (p3360a), requested by my-dependency
➤ YN0086: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
```

We're running `yarn-4.0.0-rc.48`. We're not using zero-installs, and we are using workspaces.